# Antonym of "insightful"

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym of *insightful*? I want to say that the information provided is not insightful. I searched in various dictionaries. The most common antonym is *unperceptive*, but that does not exactly carry the meaning of *un-insightful*.

Comment: [insightless](http://books.google.com/books?id=F70QLNUYvO4C&pg=PA13&dq=insightless&hl=en&ei=67yyTtDjGcWWOun3le8B&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CGMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=insightless&f=false) is not unheard of

Comment: Information itself is not insightful or shallow or trite. Those are all descriptive of a person who is attempting to come up with information. Information is simple or complex. A trite person may be only capable of coming up with simple information.

Comment: What's wrong with `uninsightful`? I have heard and seen people use it.

Comment: There is plenty of good antonyms at the http://thesaurus.com/browse/insightful page

Comment: @altern: from that site: dense, insensitive, unaware, unobservant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `obvious` or `pedestrian` to imply that any old Joe off the street could have thought up the same thing. Obvious is the word the US Patent Office uses to indicate that an idea isn't original or creative enough to be patentable.

For someone who flat out doesn't come up with much in the way of ideas at all, the term used the most is probably `unimaginative`.

Comment: I like obvious than pedestrian. The word pedestrian does not sound common-speak.

Comment: @karlos - Me too. Calling someone or something `pedestrian` makes the speaker sound rather snooty. It's really best used if the target of the phrase themselves evidentally feels superior to everyone else (to hit them where it hurts).

Comment: "Pedestrian" is something you hear often in classical music circles, where being snooty is a desideratum.

Answer (score 4):

[Obtuse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obtuse) - lacking in sharpness or quickness of sensibility and intellect.

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

> The information provided was unimaginative.

or

> The information provided was shallow.

or

> The information provided was trite.

or go with a negation like this ...

> The information provided was less piercing and insightful than trite and unimaginative.

Comment: I was thinking of trite at first. I like the negation example, because it gives context to what I am expecting as well.

Answer (score 1):

[insightful](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=insightful&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=kbayTpzfM4Wk8QOazvicBQ&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6487d6338155cbd1&biw=1221&bih=846) - *Having or showing an accurate and deep understanding; perceptive*.

[superficial](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbs=dfn:1&source=hp&q=superficial&pbx=1&oq=superficial&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=98891l101469l1l102297l11l11l0l5l5l0l203l859l1.4.1l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=97764047ff60378d&biw=1221&bih=846) - **Not** *thorough, deep, or complete; cursory*

Answer (score 0):

The adjective *insightful* is defined as

> exhibiting insight or clear and deep perception

Antonyms of this are: *shortsighted* or *unperceptive, unperceiving* (also the words others mentioned: *superficial*, *obvious*, *shallow*, *trite*; notice that it depends what you are denying *insightful* observer and *insightful* observation have different antonyms)

On a side note, I believe that you can coin a word with no problems i.e. in the spirit of the English language: ***insightless*** (and you would not be the [first](http://www.google.com/search?q=insightless&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1))

Answer (score 0):

- [Obscure](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obscure)
- [Obfuscated](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obfuscate)
- [Vague](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vague)
- [Murky](https://www.lexico.com/definition/murky)
- [Nebulous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nebulous)

Insightful connotes deep understanding and clear articulation. The above choices reflect the opposite of clarity in thought or expression.

Answer (score 0):

> The information provided is ***as clear as mud***.

or

> The information provided has ***a high cost-benefit ratio***.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the word [banal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/banal)?

> So lacking in originality as to be obvious and boring.